# Splitting blog and main site into two different webmaster and anlytics profiles - best practice?

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console

We have a site running on a main domain http://lightandspace.co.uk (60 indexed pages), and a blog running under the subdomain http://blog.lightandspace.co.uk (250 indexed pages)

I currently have them running under two Analytics profiles and two Webmaster profiles. Just so traffic figures don't get muddled, is this bad practice from an SEO point of view?

Comment: SEO is about making your site better for search engines. I don't see how you use analytics will directly affect that.

Comment: My thought was that by having the blog split into a seperate webmaster profile the main site would not be getting the befit of google seeing regularly added content

Comment: Google does not use the fact that you have analytics when updating its index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's perfectly fine, your main domain and blog each have their own sitemaps and are uniquely verified domains so two domains in Webmaster Tools is fine and same with Analytics.